# How to find the number of subarrays in a given array whose sum is zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find the number of subarray whose sum is 0 in a given array in javascript. I am explaining my code below.

I have the below given array

```
var arr = [1, -3, 2, 3, 6, -1];
```

here the expected output should be `1`. similarly for below array the output should be 2.

```
var arr =[4, 8, 9, -4, 1, -1, -8, -9]
```

Here I need how many numbers of subarray whose sum is 0 using javascript.

Comment: where is your code? btw, i see more sub arrays.

Comment: Actually I need the JavaScript code to print result.

Comment: what's the traversal criteria, because your first array has multiple sub-zero arrays at least 3

Comment: But the expected output is already given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you are searching for

```js
let arr1 = [1, -3, 2, 3, 6, -1];
let arr2 = [4, 8, 9, -4, 1, -1, -8, -9];
let arr3 = [6, 3, -1, -3, 4, -2, 2, 4, 6, -12, -7];

function countZeroSumSubArray(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      sum += arr[j];
      if (!sum) {
        ++counter;
      }
    }

  }
  return counter
}

console.log('amount:', countZeroSumSubArray(arr1))
console.log('amount:', countZeroSumSubArray(arr2))
console.log('amount:', countZeroSumSubArray(arr3))
```

Comment: This is working fine but the nested foor loop may take much time to execute if array length is long.

Comment: That's a naive solution just to get you going, if you want it optimised please post another question..